# Issues with setting variable value to what user selects from drop down menu in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, menu, tkinter

I have created a turtle graphics program that draws the letters associated with any of the keys on the keyboard that the user types. The user can also press a tkinter button on the bottom of the turtle canvas to change the height/width of each letter using the turtle module's `numinput()` widget. I have also created a tkinter drop down menu (attached to a tkinter menu button) to which (for now) only the new changed letter width is written to every time it is changed by the user. The menu/menu button is created through the following code block which is located BELOW the function which changes the letter height/width, so the values must be `global`:

```
global hjk
hjk = Menubutton(text = "Previous widths", state = DISABLED)
hjk.pack(side = "left")
hjk.menu = Menu(hjk, tearoff = 0)
hjk["menu"] = hjk.menu
global do
do = hjk.menu
hjk.pack()
```

and every time the width is changed, the menu button is enabled, and the new width is attached to the menu through the method below, which is also embedded below the code block that allows the width to change according to user input:

```
global letter_width
hjk.config(state = NORMAL)
user_width_input = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width (Number between 10-170): ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
letter_width = letter_width if user_width_input is None else user_width_input
global widthy
widthy = IntVar()
# The following writes the changed letter width to the menu each time it is changed by the user
global hlf
hlf = []
hlf.append(letter_width)
for letter_width in hlf:
   do.add_command(label = str(letter_width), command = lambda letter_width=letter_width: changeletterwidth(letter_width))
```

**EDIT:** My issue is with the `changeletterwidth` command embedded in the `do.add_command` menu command above. That function is supposed to change the letter width **globally** to the value selected from the menu by the user. I have created the following for `changeletterwidth`:

```
def changeletterwidth(width):
    global letter_width
    widthy.set(width)
```

However, **it does not work**, since even when I select a value from the drop down menu, the **letter width still stays the same as before**. ***What am I doing wrong here and how would I fix it?*** Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated! :)

Comment: use `global letter_width` in `changeletterwidth` ?

Comment: @furas Yes, I did that, but I need to know HOW to capture the value from the menu. Just putting `global letter_width` won't do the trick.

Comment: I fouth you have only one value in menu and you have the same value in `letter_width` - so you don't need to get value from menu. You can assign command with argument using `lambda` this way: `command=lambda w=letter_width:changeletterwidth(w)` and declare function with argument `def changeletterwidth(width):`

Comment: @furas Nope, it still does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is `widthy` ? I thought you want to change `letter_width`.

Comment: @furas `widthy` is an `IntVar()`. I thought that would help me change the value, but yes, I want to change letter width. I tried to do `letter_width.set(width)`, but it still did not work.

Comment: moment - do you want to change variable `letter_width` or do you want to change width of some letter which you have somewhere (on screen or on canvas) ?

Comment: @furas I want to change the variable `letter_width` **globally** so its value would apply to EVERYTHING that utilizes that variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100255/discussion-between-r-kap-and-furas).

Comment: Now I see. But it doesn't work this way. When you change `letter_width` you have to redraw all element using new `letter_width`.

Comment: @furas It is fixed now! All I had to do was put `update()` and `listen()` in the `changeletterwidth` definition.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed. FINALLY figured it out, and it was so simple, the solution completely flew over my head. All I had to do was add `update()` and `listen()` to the `changeletterwidth` function, like so:

```
def changeletterwidth(width):
    global letter_width
    letter_width = (width)
    update() #<-- Here...
    listen()#<-- and here.
```